# how to change dimension of image in node-canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-canvas

I have drawn some pictures in node-canvas and I want to print them and I want them to be the actual size in centimeters.
For example, I have drawn a circle with a radius of 50 and I want the printed circle to have a radius of 50 cm when I print this image.
how can i do this?